# .htaccess being ignored in sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I'm trying to get my `.htaccess` file to work from the root, but also use `RewriteRule` for a sub-directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/index.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?_pd=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_pd=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However I get 404 errors when trying to access `/admin/login` etc etc. This kind of works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_pd=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/index.php$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?_pd=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But not how it should do. Some things work, some don't.

Comment: If this .htaccess is in `/admin/` folder, then pattern in rewrite rule should not contain `admin/` part (URL will be relative to the current folder).

Comment: Well .. since I do not have all the details -- I can suggest swap the 2 rules around (your second example) -- move 3-lines block below the 4-lines block. This should process `/admin/xxx` URLs, as right now the `/index.php` taking all URLs (order of rules matters) and `/admin/` rule is never matched.

Comment: This gives me a `404` although I know that `/admin/index.php` is there.

Comment: Well.. under such conditions I can only recommend turning on rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log. Please also check access rights for `/admin/index.php` (just in case).

Comment: `RewriteLogLevel` directive cannot be placed in .htaccess -- only in server config or virtual host context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually caused because I had missed out on including that there is an `ErrorDocument` in the `.htaccess` apparently, since the `admin` folder didn't include this same document, it wasn't following the rules like it should, and trying to supply me with that file instead.